# Possibilities Hexagon Coloring

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

we colored vertices of a hexagon convex  by three different colors ; such that every color appears exactly only two times in the vertices .
Find the number of possibilities in order to get every vertice of this hexagon colored such that any two neighboring points have distinct colors.

The answer must be either 4 or 5.

**Can we generalize the solution to a problem like this?**
we colored vertices of a **2n**-gon convex  by **n** different colors ; such that every color appears exactly only two times in the vertices .
Find the number of possibilities in order to get every vertice of this convex colored such that any two neighboring points have distinct colors.

please post some hints. I don't want actually a full solution.

Comment: What does "...every **top** of this hexagon..." mean?

Comment: top = vertice , sorry , this is my third year learning English

Comment: No problem, I understand now. There is a general method that uses generating functions for the cycle index of such a combinatorial "necklace".

Comment: thanks , I'll try to search this "necklace"

Comment: I didn't find enough explanation . any good pdf / website explaining "necklace"?

Comment: [Wiki link for combinatorial necklace](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)). This is the standard definition, however there is some modification to the cycle index needed due to the condition on adjacent vertices. I have some work on this but it's not a simple formula.

Comment: Ah , yeah , just to check , what's the formula of the possibilities without the restriction ".. **every vertice of this convex colored such that any two neighboring points have distinct colors.** ...

Comment: If you wish to specify the number of each colour being used then it is the coefficient found using the [cycle index](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_index) to express the pattern index. I am assuming you want to exclude colourings that are identical under rotation. Also [see](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pólya_enumeration_theorem).

Comment: What do you mean, "the answer must be either 4 or 5"? Say the three colors are red, white, and blue. There are already 9 ways to choose the two red vertices. If the two red vertices are diametrically opposite, then there are 4 ways to color the remaining vertices. ***Did you leave something out of the problem?***

Comment: bof , if you consider rotation and reflection as the same colouring, then there are only 4 , but if you consider rotation to be the same. there will be 5 indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We present  the five  non-isomorphic proper  colorings of  the hexagon
with  two  instances  of   three  different  colors  under  rotational
symmetry for the reader to peruse in retracing the symmetries.

[image: Coloring the hexagon]

The Maple code for this was as follows.

```
with(combinat);

PLOTCIRCNOADJ3 :=
proc()
local n, src, neckl, pos, perm, orbits, orbit, uniqorbs,
    nxt, loc, fd, current, vert1, vert2,
    line, prolog, rot, colors, bbox;

    orbits := table();

    n := 3;
    src := [seq(q, q=1..n), seq(q, q=1..n)];

    for perm in permute(src) do
        neckl := [op(perm), perm[1]];

        for pos to 2*n do
            if neckl[pos] = neckl[pos+1] then
                break;
            fi;
        od;

        if pos = 2*n+1 then
            orbit := [];

            for rot to 2*n do
                nxt :=
                [seq(perm[q], q=rot..2*n),
                 seq(perm[q], q=1..rot-1)];
                orbit := [op(orbit), nxt];
            od;

            orbits[sort(orbit)[1]] := 1;
        fi;

    od;

    uniqorbs := [indices(orbits, 'nolist')];

    fd := fopen(`noniso-circnoadj3.ps`, WRITE);

    bbox := [120, 600];

    prolog :=
    ["%!PS-Adobe-1.0",
     "%%Creator: Marko Riedel",
     "%%Title: graph orbits",
     sprintf("%%%%BoundingBox: 0 0 %d %d", bbox[1], bbox[2]),
     "%%Pages: 1",
     "%%EndComments"];

    for line in prolog do
        fprintf(fd, "%s\n", line);
    od;

    fprintf(fd, "%%Page 1 1\n\n");

    colors :=
    [[1,0,0], [0,0,1], [1,1,0]];

    fprintf(fd, "8 setlinewidth 0 0.72 0 setrgbcolor\n");
    fprintf(fd, "0 0 moveto %d 0 lineto %d %d lineto\n",
            bbox[1], bbox[1], bbox[2]);
    fprintf(fd, "0 %d lineto closepath stroke\n",
           bbox[2]);

    fprintf(fd, "0.05 setlinewidth 0 setgray\n");

    fprintf(fd, "30 30 scale\n");

    for current to nops(uniqorbs) do
        fprintf(fd, "gsave\n");
        fprintf(fd, "%f %f translate\n",
                2, 2+4*(current-1));

        for pos from 0 to 5 do
            loc := exp(2*Pi*I*pos/6);
            vert1 := [Re(loc), Im(loc)];

            loc := exp(2*Pi*I*(pos+1)/6);
            vert2 := [Re(loc), Im(loc)];

            fprintf(fd, "%f %f moveto\n",
                   vert1[1], vert1[2]);
            fprintf(fd, "%f %f lineto\n",
                   vert2[1], vert2[2]);

            fprintf(fd, "closepath stroke\n");

            fprintf(fd, "gsave\n");

            fprintf(fd, "%f %f translate\n",
                    (vert1[1]+vert2[1])/2,
                    (vert1[2]+vert2[2])/2);

            fprintf(fd, "0.2 0.2 scale\n");

            fprintf(fd, "%f rotate\n",
                    90 + (pos-1)*60);

            fprintf(fd, "-0.5 0 moveto\n");
            fprintf(fd, "0.5 0 lineto\n");
            fprintf(fd, "0 2 lineto\n");

            fprintf(fd, "closepath fill\n");

            fprintf(fd, "grestore\n");
        od;

        for pos to 6 do
            loc := exp(2*Pi*I*(pos-1)/6);
            vert1 := [Re(loc), Im(loc)];

            fprintf(fd, "%f %f %f setrgbcolor\n",
                   colors[uniqorbs[current][pos]][1],
                   colors[uniqorbs[current][pos]][2],
                   colors[uniqorbs[current][pos]][3]);
            fprintf(fd, "%f %f 0.24 0 360 arc\n",
                    vert1[1], vert1[2]);
            fprintf(fd, "fill\n");


            fprintf(fd, "0 0 0 setrgbcolor\n");
            fprintf(fd, "%f %f 0.24 0 360 arc\n",
                    vert1[1], vert1[2]);
            fprintf(fd, "stroke\n");
        od;

        fprintf(fd, "grestore\n");
    od;


    fprintf(fd, "showpage\n");
    fclose(fd);

    true;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

## First hint.

Consult                            this                           [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2164399/) to learn how a
closely related problem was solved.

## Second hint.

There is a Perl script that computes the first six proper colorings of
an  $2n$-gon  using  two  instances  of  $n$  different  colors,  with
rotational symmetries  being taken  into account  and not  being taken
into account. The data that were obtained go like this: for no symmetries
we find

$$0, 2, 24, 744, 35160, 2394720, \ldots$$

and with rotational symmetries taken into account

$$0, 1, 5, 96, 3528, 199620, \ldots $$

The reader may use these to check their computational results.

## Third hint.

The relevant cycle index is

$$Z(C_{2n}) = \frac{1}{2n} \sum_{d|2n} \varphi(d) a_d^{2n/d}.$$

Can you determine  the number of proper colorings fixed  by each shape
of  permutation and  apply Burnside?   There are  only three  cases, a
trivial one, one that can be  solved by inspection and one that yields
to a simple argument by inclusion-exclusion. Substitute these into the
cycle index to  obtain the second sequence, you  will have encountered
the first one at this point. You should now have a simple formula that
lets you compute enough of these  two sequences to qualify for a query
of / a new  entry in the OEIS, where it appears the  second one is not
included yet. The first one provides a particularly relevant entry.

## For consultation.

The Perl script goes like this.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
#

sub choose2n {
    my ($n, $slots, $sofar, $func, @fargs) = @_;
    my $len = scalar( @{ $sofar } );

    if($len == $n){
        my @data = (0) x (2*$n);

        for(my $val = 0; $val < $n; $val++){
            $data[$sofar->[$val]->[0]] = $val;
            $data[$sofar->[$val]->[1]] = $val;
        }

        &$func(\@data, @fargs);
        return;
    }

    my $rest = 2*$n - 2*$len;
    for(my $p=0; $p < $rest; $p++){
        for(my $q=$p+1; $q < $rest; $q++){
            my ($pos1, $pos2) = 
                ($slots->[$p], $slots->[$q]);

            next if $pos1 + 1 == $pos2 ||
                ($pos1 == 0 && $pos2 == 2*$n-1);

            splice @$slots, $q, 1;
            splice @$slots, $p, 1;

            push @$sofar, [$pos1, $pos2];
            choose2n($n, $slots, $sofar, 
                     $func, @fargs);
            pop @$sofar;

            splice @$slots, $p, 0, $pos1;
            splice @$slots, $q, 0, $pos2;
        }
    }
}

sub account {
    my ($dref, $n, $orbref, $nosymref) = @_;

    $$nosymref++;

    my %orbit;
    for(my $shft = 0; $shft < 2*$n; $shft++){
        my $str =
            join('-', 
                 @$dref[$shft..2*$n-1], 
                 @$dref[0..$shft-1]);
        $orbit{$str} = 1;
    }

    my $orbstr = (sort(keys %orbit))[0];
    $orbref->{$orbstr} = 1;
}

MAIN : {
    my $mx = shift || 10;
    my $k = shift || 2;

    my @nosymres = (0); my @res = (0);

    for(my $n=2; $n <= $mx; $n++){
        my %orbits = (); my $nosym = 0;

        my @src = (0..(2*$n-1));
        choose2n($n, \@src, [], 
                 \&account, $n, \%orbits, \$nosym);

        push @nosymres, $nosym;
        push @res, scalar(keys %orbits);
    }

    print join(', ', @res);
    print "\n";

    print join(', ', @nosymres);
    print "\n";

    1;
}
```

## More hints as per request

Web resources to consult are

- [Wikipedia on cycle indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_index)

[MSE Meta on Polya/Burnside](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions#13335)

*How  to compute  with  the cycle  index.*  Consider the  $\varphi(d)$
permutations  with cycle  shape  $a_d^{2n/d}$ where  $d|2n.$ We  apply
Burnside and ask  how many of the proper colorings  are fixed by these
permutations. Note however that no coloring can be constant on a cycle
of length $d$  where $d\gt 2$ because there are  only two instances of
each color, for a zero contribution.  This leaves $d=1$ and $d=2.$ The
latter case has permutation shape $a_2^n.$  In order to be constant on
these $n$ two-cycles we must place  a permutation of the two instances
of each color  on the two-cycles which can be  done in $n!$ ways.(This
automatically ensures that two identical colors are never next to each
other.)  We are  left  to ask  how  many colorings  are  fixed by  the
identity permutation. These are precisely  the proper colorings of the
$2n$-gon  with   no  symmetries   and  we   can  compute   these  with
inclusion-exclusion.   The  nodes  $P$  of the  poset  here  represent
colorings  where the  colors  in  $P$ are  next  to  each other,  plus
possibly some more pairs that are  also next to each other. The weight
of such a node is $(-1)^{|P|}.$  This means that the colorings with no
identical neighbors are only included when $P$ is the empty set, for a
weight of  one. Colorings with exactly  $p$ colors next to  each other
are included in all nodes $Q$ that are subsets of these $p$ colors $P$
for a contribution of

$$\sum_{q=0}^p {p\choose q} (-1)^q = 0$$

because $p\ge 1$ for a total weight of zero. Now to actually count the
elements of $P$ we have two possibilities. First, none of the pairs of
colors are placed  on the special wrap-around slot  pair that connects
the     last     element     to     the     first.      This     gives
$\frac{(2n-2p+p)!}{2^{n-p}}$       or      $$\frac{(2n-p)!}{2^{n-p}}$$
possibilities.   Second, one  of the  pairs is  located on  the bridge
slot. That  means we  must choose the  pair, for a  factor of  $p$ and
permute      the      rest,       for      a      contribution      of
$p\frac{(2n-2p+p-1)!}{2^{n-p}}$ or  $$p\frac{(2n-p-1)!}{2^{n-p}}.$$ We
thus obtain  for colorings  with no symmetries  taken into  account by
inclusion-exclusion for $n\ge 2$

$$\sum_{p=0}^n {n\choose p} \frac{(-1)^p}{2^{n-p}}
((2n-p)! + p(2n-p-1)!).$$

This is the following sequence, which is now easy to calculate:

$$2, 2, 24, 744, 35160, 2394720, 222712560, 27154350720, 
\\ 4205374225920, 806700010233600, 187793061031699200, 
\\ 52162131258836121600,\ldots$$

Substituting  this  into the  cycle  index  we obtain  for  rotational
symmetries taken into account

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{\frac{1}{2} (n-1)! +
\frac{1}{2n} \sum_{p=0}^n {n\choose p} \frac{(-1)^p}{2^{n-p}}
((2n-p)! + p(2n-p-1)!).}$$

We  may  thus  compute   the  sequence  under  rotational  symmetries,
confirming and extending  the values from the Perl  script, which used
enumeration. We obtain

$$1, 1, 5, 96, 3528, 199620, 15908400, 1697149440, 233631921600, 
\\ 40335000693120, 8536048230528000, 
\\ 2173422135804796800,\ldots$$

## Solving the case of dihedral symmetry

We get for the cycle index

$$Z(D_{2n}) = \frac{1}{4n} \sum_{d|2n} \varphi(d) a_d^{2n/d}
+ \frac{1}{4} a_1^2 a_2^{n-1} + \frac{1}{4} a_2^n.$$

Observe that the  permutations with shape $a_2^n$  swap adjacent beads
(those  immediately  to  the  left  and  the  right  of  the  axis  of
reflection) which would have  to be the same color as  they are on the
same  two-cycle.    This  is   impossible  so   this  term   does  not
contribute. On the other hand for  the shape $a_1^2 a_2^{n-1}$ we must
place pairs of colors on  the two-cycles, leaving two identical colors
on  the  slots  that  are  fixed  and are  situated  on  the  axis  of
reflection. This yields $n\times (n-1)!$ possibilities. We get for our
answer

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{\frac{1}{4} (n-1)! +
+ \frac{1}{4} n! +
\frac{1}{4n} \sum_{p=0}^n {n\choose p} \frac{(-1)^p}{2^{n-p}}
((2n-p)! + p(2n-p-1)!).}$$

This yields the following sequence.

$$0, 1, 4, 54, 1794, 99990, 7955460, 848584800, 116816051520, 
\\ 20167501253760, 4268024125243200, 1086711068022148800,\ldots $$

The Perl  code for  this version  has a different  function to  do the
accounting.

```
sub account {
    my ($dref, $n, $orbref, $nosymref) = @_;

    $$nosymref++;

    my %orbit;

    for(my $shft = 0; $shft < 2*$n; $shft++){
        my (@data) = 
            (@$dref[$shft..2*$n-1], 
             @$dref[0..$shft-1]);

        my $str = join('-', @data);
        $orbit{$str} = 1;

        for(my $swap = 0; $swap < $n; $swap++){
            my $tmp = $data[$swap];
            $data[$swap] = $data[2*$n-1-$swap];
            $data[2*$n-1-$swap] = $tmp;
        }

        $str = join('-', @data);
        $orbit{$str} = 1;
    }

    my $orbstr = (sort(keys %orbit))[0];
    $orbref->{$orbstr} = 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Marko. I'm not familiar too much with cycle index and Burnside. can you give me some courses which can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For a hexagon, careful counting will get you there.  The first color can either have its two vertices opposite or next but one to each other.  If they are opposite, the next color can either be opposite or both next to the same one of the first, two choices.  If the first color is next but one, placing a color in the space between them forces everything, so two more for a total of four.  If you count by hand the first few you can look in OEIS to see if you can find the sequence.  That often finds references.

Comment: I tried to do so . but I failed :(