# A bracelet has $n$ $ϵ$ $Z_+$ colored beads. Show that the number of different bracelets with at most $λ$ different colors on the beads is given by

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, symmetry

A bracelet (circle) has $n$ $ϵ$ $Z_+$ colored beads. Show that the number of different bracelets (taking into consideration all symmetries) with at most $λ$ different colors on the beads and no beads of the same color next to each other is given by:
$\frac{1}{2n}*(\sum_{d|n}phi(d)((λ-1)^{\frac{n}{d}}+(-1)^{\frac{n}{d}}(λ-1))+0)$ if $n$ is even
$\frac{1}{2n}*(\sum_{d|n}phi(d)((λ-1)^{\frac{n}{d}}+(-1)^{\frac{n}{d}}(λ-1))+{\frac{n}{d}}λ(λ-1)^{\frac{n}{d}})$ if $n$ is odd
where $\sum_{d|n}phi(d)$ is the sum over positive $d$ that divides $n$ and $phi()$ is Euler's totient function.

Hi everyone, I'm completely lost on this one. Do anyone know how to get the wanted result?

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Are you familiar with Burnside's lemma? Apply it to the action of the dihedral group on the set of bracelets (with no beads of the same color next to each other).

Answer (score 0):

The solution for cyclical symmetries only has already appeared at this
[MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2164399/)  and was
found to be (notation from link)

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{d|n} \varphi(n/d) P_d(k)$$

where $$P_d(k) = (k-1)^d + (-1)^d \times (k-1).$$

Now we just need to account  for reflections which constitute the rest
of the dihedral group. Note that when $n$ is odd these reflections fix
one bead and the  two adjacent beads just opposite end  up on the same
cycle, which is  not a proper coloring, for a  contribution of zero or
for $n$ odd

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{d|n} \varphi(n/d) P_d(k).}$$

On the other hand for $n$ even there are two types of reflections, the
first about an axis passing through midpoints of opposite edges. These
place  the beads  on  those edges  on two-cycles  and  since they  are
adjacent  we get  no proper  colorings. The  other type  of reflection
fixes two opposite beads. There are $n/2$ of these reflections and the
left side determines  the right and vice versa. We  have $n/2+1$ beads
for $k\times (k-1)^{n/2}$ colorings.  Hence we get for $n$ even

$$\frac{1}{2n} \sum_{d|n} \varphi(n/d) P_d(k)
+ \frac{1}{2n} \frac{n}{2} \times k \times (k-1)^{n/2}$$

which is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{1}{2n} \sum_{d|n} \varphi(n/d) P_d(k)
+ \frac{k}{4}(k-1)^{n/2}.}$$

There  is also  a  Perl script  that verifies  these  two formulae  by
enumeration.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
#

MAIN : {
    my $mx = shift || 10;
    my $k = shift || 2;

    my @res = ($k);

    for(my $n=2; $n <= $mx; $n++){
        my %orbits;

        for(my $ind = 0; $ind < $k ** $n; $ind++){
            my ($pos, $idx, @d);

            for(($pos, $idx) = (0, $ind); 
                $pos < $n; $pos++){
                my $digit = $idx % $k;

                push @d, $digit;
                $idx = ($idx-$digit) / $k;
            }

            for($pos=0; $pos < $n; $pos++){
                last if $d[$pos] == $d[($pos+1) % $n];
            }

            if($pos == $n){
                my %orbit;
                for(my $shft = 0; $shft < $n; $shft++){
                    my (@rot) =
                        (@d[$shft..$n-1], @d[0..$shft-1]);

                    my $str = join('-', @rot);
                    $orbit{$str} = 1;

                    $str = join('-', reverse(@rot));
                    $orbit{$str} = 1;
                }

                my $orbstr = (sort(keys %orbit))[0];
                $orbits{$orbstr} = 1;
            }
        }

        push @res, scalar(keys %orbits);
    }

    print join(', ', @res);
    print "\n";

    1;
}
```