# Tree Graphs Colorings With K Colors

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees, coloring

[image]

For each of the trees, how many different ways are there of coloring the
vertices with k colors such that adjacent vertices are colored with different colors and so that **two colorings of the graph are considered different if there is no rearrangement of the vertices so that they look the same**?

i dont understand the last bit

Answer (score 4):

#### Algorithm and answer to query

A Google search will reveal that  these graph colorings are counted by
so-called  *orbital chromatic  polynomials*  (as  opposed to  ordinary
chromatic polynomials). These count  proper colorings under the action
of the automorphism group of the graph.

The algorithm to compute these is documented e.g.  at [Peter Cameron's
blog](https://cameroncounts.wordpress.com/2012/04/12/). This is really
quite straightforward  supposing that  the number of  automorphisms of
the  graph is  of a  reasonable order,  e.g. linear  in the  number of
vertices as  in the case of  a bracelet. What  we do here is  to apply
Burnside, iterating over all automorphisms and computing the number of
proper colorings that they fix and  averaging the results.  To do this
we factorize the automorphisms into cycles,  on which the color has to
be  constant. Therefore  we have  no contribution  if a  cycle of  the
factored automorphism  contains two vertices  linked by an  edge since
these may not be monochrome in  a proper coloring. Otherwise we shrink
all the  cycles to vertices, creating  a reduced graph, where  two new
vertices are adjacent if there existed an edge between the vertices on
the  cycles  in  the  source  graph.   The  colorings  fixed  by  this
automorphism are then counted by  the ordinary chromatic polynomial of
the  reduced  graph.   Hence  the *orbital  chromatic  polynomial*  is
obtained by averaging these over the number of automorphisms.

It is not difficult to implement this  in Maple, where the goal was to
get a functioning program to answer  the question, which may of course
be optimized  in many  ways.  We  decided on  a simple  data structure
representing  graphs and  their automorphism  group by  a list  of the
edges, the  number of vertices,  and the permutations from  the group.
We use  these as inputs to  Burnside where we carry  out the iteration
that we  described, obtaining the  OCP. Numbering the four  trees from
left to right we thus obtain for the first tree,

$$1/8\,{k}^{7}-1/2\,{k}^{6}+1/4\,{k}^{2}-1/4\,{k}^{4}
\\-3/8\,{k}^{3}+3/4\,{k}^{5},$$

for the second one,

$$1/6\,{k}^{7}-{k}^{6}+3\,{k}^{5}-16/3\,{k}^{4}
\\+{\frac {35\,{k}^{3}}{6}}-11/3\,{k}^{2}+k$$

for the third one

$$1/24\,{k}^{7}-1/6\,{k}^{5}+1/12\,{k}^{4}
\\+1/8\,{k}^{3}-1/12\,{k}^{2}$$

and for the last one,

$$1/12\,{k}^{7}-1/6\,{k}^{6}+1/6\,{k}^{4}-1/12\,{k}^{3}.$$

The admissible colorings under the action of the automorphism group of
the  tree are  then computed  by instantiating  $k$ to  the number  of
colors.

#### Sanity checks and more

With these  trees having a  reasonable number of automorphisms  we can
check the  correctness of  the OCP by  enumerating colorings  with few
colors.  This  was done and  may be seen  in the attached  Maple code.
E.g. for tree number three the enumeration routine produces

$$0, 2, 60, 540, 2800, 10500,\ldots $$

which is indeed given by the polynomial listed above.

Similarly  the question  of  proper colorings  of bracelets  (dihedral
symmetry)       recently       appeared       at       this       [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2583968/).   This forms
the second sanity check where for example we obtain matching OCPs from
the cited link  and the present document. E.g. for  a bracelet on five
beads we obtain by both methods

$$1/10\,{k}^{5}-1/2\,{k}^{4}+{k}^{3}-{k}^{2}+2/5\,k$$

and for six beads,

$$1/12\,{k}^{6}-1/2\,{k}^{5}+3/2\,{k}^{4}-7/3\,{k}^{3}
+{\frac {23\,{k}^{2}}{12}}-2/3\,k.$$

#### Maple code

We  now present  the Maple  code which  uses only  one routine  from a
library  of  Polya Enumeration  code  while  the rest  translates  the
specification of the algorithm with little auxiliary effort required.

```
with(GraphTheory);
with(combinat);

T1 :=
proc()
option remember;

    return
    [7,
     {{1,2}, {1, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5},
      {3, 6}, {3, 7}},
     [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
      [1,2,3,5,4,6,7],
      [1,2,3,4,5,7,6],
      [1,2,3,5,4,7,6],
      [1,3,2,6,7,4,5],
      [1,3,2,7,6,4,5],
      [1,3,2,6,7,5,4],
      [1,3,2,7,6,5,4]]];
end;

T2 :=
proc()
option remember;
local automs, src, perm;

    src := [[2,3], [4,5], [6,7]];
    automs := [];

    for perm in permute(3) do
        automs :=
        [op(automs),
         [1,
          seq(op(src[perm[q]]),
              q=1..3)]];
    od;

    return
    [7,
     {{1, 2}, {1, 4}, {1, 6},
      {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7}},
     automs];
end;

T3 :=
proc()
option remember;
local automs, perm;

    automs := [];

    for perm in permute(4) do
        automs :=
        [op(automs),
         [1,2,3, seq(perm[q]+3, q=1..4)]];
    od;

    return
    [7,
     {{1, 2}, {2, 3},
      {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}, {1, 7}},
     automs];
end;

T4 :=
proc()
option remember;
local automs, perm1, perm2;

    automs := [];

    for perm1 in permute(2) do
        for perm2 in permute(3) do
            automs :=
            [op(automs),
             [1, 2,
              seq(perm1[q]+2, q=1..2),
              seq(perm2[q]+4, q=1..3)]];
        od;
    od;

    return
    [7,
     {{1, 2}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}, {1, 7},
      {2, 3}, {2, 4}},
     automs];
end;

BRACELET :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local automs, rot, shft, edges;

    if n=1 then return [1, {}, [[1]]] fi;

    automs := [];

    for rot to n do
        shft :=
        [seq(q, q=rot..n), seq(q, q=1..rot-1)];

        automs :=
        [op(automs),
         shft, [seq(shft[n-q], q=0..n-1)]];
    od;

    edges :=
    {{n, 1},
     seq({q, q+1}, q=1..n-1)};

    return [n, edges, automs];
end;

pet_autom2cyclesA :=
proc(src, aut)
local numa, numsubs;
local marks, pos, cycs, data, item, cpos, clen;

    numsubs := [seq(src[k]=k, k=1..nops(src))];
    numa := subs(numsubs, aut);

    marks := Array([seq(true, pos=1..nops(aut))]);

    cycs := []; pos := 1; data := [];

    while pos <= nops(aut) do
        if marks[pos] then
            clen := 0; item := []; cpos := pos;

            while marks[cpos] do
                marks[cpos] := false;
                item := [op(item), aut[cpos]];

                cpos := numa[cpos];
                clen := clen+1;
            od;

            cycs := [op(cycs), clen];
            data := [op(data), item];
        fi;

        pos := pos+1;
    od;

    return [data, mul(a[cycs[k]], k=1..nops(cycs))];
end;


OCP :=
proc(tdata)
option remember;
local n, edges, automs, autom, src,
    cycs, cidx, ccount, admit, edg,
    potedg, rededgs, cdx1, cdx2, c1, c2, redG, ocp;

    n := tdata[1];
    edges := tdata[2];
    automs := tdata[3];

    src := [seq(q, q=1..n)];

    ocp := 0;
    for autom in automs do
        cycs := pet_autom2cyclesA(src, autom)[1];
        ccount := nops(cycs);

        admit := true; cidx := 1;
        while admit and cidx <= ccount do
            for edg in choose(cycs[cidx], 2) do
                if {edg[1], edg[2]} in
                edges then
                    admit := false;
                    break;
                fi;
            od;

            cidx := cidx + 1;
        od;

        if admit then
            rededgs := {};

            for cdx1 to ccount do
                for cdx2 from cdx1+1 to ccount do
                    c1 := cycs[cdx1]; c2 := cycs[cdx2];

                    potedg :=
                    {seq(seq({c1[p], c2[q]},
                             p=1..nops(c1)), q=1..nops(c2))};

                    if edges intersect potedg <> {} then
                        rededgs :=
                        {op(rededgs), {cdx1, cdx2}};
                    fi;
                od;
            od;

            redG :=
            Graph([seq(q, q=1..ccount)], rededgs);

            ocp := ocp +
            ChromaticPolynomial(redG, 'k');
        fi;
    od;

    expand(ocp/nops(automs));
end;

X := (tdata, kval) -> subs('k'=kval, OCP(tdata));

ENUM :=
proc(tdata, k)
option remember;
local n, edges, edg, admit, automs, autom,
    orbits, orbit, idx, cols;

    n := tdata[1];
    edges := tdata[2];
    automs := tdata[3];

    if k=1 then
        return `if`(nops(edges)=0, 1, 0);
    fi;

    orbits := table();

    for idx from k^n to 2*k^n-1 do
        cols := convert(idx, base, k)[1..n];

        admit := true;
        for edg in edges do
            if cols[op(1, edg)] = cols[op(2, edg)]
            then
                admit := false;
                break;
            fi;
        od;

        if not admit then next fi;

        orbit := [];

        for autom in automs do
            orbit :=
            [op(orbit),
             [seq(cols[autom[q]], q=1..n)]];
        od;

        orbits[sort(orbit)[1]] := 1;
    od;

    numelems(orbits);
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

For example in the first graph the coloring:

$A\\B-C\\D\\E-F\\G$

is "the same" that the coloring:

$G\\E-F\\D\\B-C\\A$

Comment: okay thanks, so lets say theres only two colours because the first graph only needs two colours to be coloured. would it just be

Comment: hmm but you need the minimum?

Comment: he never specified but what i meant was for each shape there would only be two unique colourings with two colours

B
W--B
B
W--B

Comment: Ah, yes. It's right

Comment: Okay great thanks now he also asked a similar question but i never got to answer it because of his wording":

**For each of the trees in the first problem, how many different ways are there of coloring the
vertices with k colors (no restriction on which colors can be used) where two colorings of
the graph are considered different if there is no rearrangement of the vertices so that the
colorings look the same?
**