# $3$-colourings of a $3×3$ table with one of $3$ colors up to symmetries

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

Color each cell of a $3×3$ table with one of $3$ colors. What is the number of ways to do so if adjacent cells have different colors?

---

Of course we consider two paintings the same (equivalent) if exist reflection or rotation which take one to another. So

$$
\begin{array} {|r|r|r|}
\hline
 \color{blue}{B}& \color{yellow}{Y} &\color{red}{R}  \\
\hline
\color{red}{R}& \color{red}{R}&\color{red}{R}\\
\hline
\color{red}{R}& \color{red}{R}& \color{red}{R} \\
\hline
\end{array}
\;\;\;\;\;{\rm and} \;\;\;\;\;
\begin{array} {|r|r|r|}
\hline
  \color{red}{R}& \color{red}{R}& \color{blue}{B} \\
\hline
 \color{red}{R}& \color{red}{R}& \color{yellow}{Y} \\
\hline
\color{red}{R}& \color{red}{R}& \color{red}{R} \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
are the same colorings.

Since marked cells are ''independent'' we can color them at random but not with all 3 colors.

\begin{array} {|r|r|r|}
\hline
 & X &  \\
\hline
X & &X \\
\hline
 & X&  \\
\hline
\end{array}

**Case 1:** If all $X$ are colored with the same color, then for each unmarked cell we have 2 posibilites. So in this case we have $3\cdot 2^{5}$ possibile colorings. But clearly some of them are equivalent. What should I do? Divide this with 4? Or 16? Something else?

**Case 2:** $Y$ is of different color then $X$. Now we have $3$ colors for $Y$ and $2$ for $X$. Rest of the places we can color $1^3\cdot 2^2$ so we have $6\cdot 2^{2}$ possibile colorings. But again reflections across midlle colum give us equivalent colorings so we should divide this by $2$?
 \begin{array} {|r|r|r|}
\hline
 & Y &  \\
\hline
X & &X \\
\hline
 & X&  \\
\hline
\end{array}

**Case 3:** ...
 \begin{array} {|r|r|r|}
\hline
 & Y &  \\
\hline
Y & &X \\
\hline
 & X&  \\
\hline
\end{array}

Is there more elegant aproach?

Answer (score 5):

We can use Burnside's lemma to account for symmetries. By the OEIS, there are 246 different 3-colourings of a labelled 3×3 grid graph (i.e. before accounting for symmetry).

This graph's non-identity symmetries are as follows. The general form of a colouring invariant under this symmetry is shown, then a calculation of the number of such colourings.

- **90° left/right rotations.** A colouring invariant under this transformation looks like this:
  $$\begin{array}{|r|r|r|}
  \hline a&b&a\\
  \hline b&c&b\\
  \hline a&b&a\\\hline\end{array}$$
  After $b$ is chosen, we have two possibilities each for $a,c$. Thus there are $3×2×2=12$ such colourings invariant under each of these symmetries.
- **180° rotation.**
  $$\begin{array}{|r|r|r|}
  \hline a&b&c\\
  \hline d&e&d\\
  \hline c&b&a\\\hline\end{array}$$
  Either $b,d$ are different colours (6 ways), in which case $a,c,e$ can only assume the third colour, or $b,d$ are the same (3 ways) and $a,c,e$ can be one of two colours. There are $6×1^3+3×2^3=30$ invariant colourings.
- **Horizontal/vertical reflections.**
  $$\begin{array}{|r|r|r|}
  \hline a&b&c\\
  \hline d&e&f\\
  \hline a&b&c\\\hline\end{array}$$
  This is equivalent to the number of 3-colourings of a 2×3 grid graph. Appealing to the OEIS again, we see that there are 54 such colourings for each symmetry.
- **Diagonal reflections.**
  $$\begin{array}{|r|r|r|}
  \hline a&b&c\\
  \hline d&e&b\\
  \hline f&d&a\\\hline\end{array}$$
  This is equivalent to the number of colourings of a square, 18 according to the OEIS, multiplied by 4, yielding 72. The square is formed by $a,b,d,e$, and for each colouring of the square $c,f$ can be either of the two colours not used for $b,d$ respectively, hence the $2^2$ multiplier.

Burnside's lemma then gives the number of colourings up to symmetries as
$$\frac{246+2×12+30+2×54+2×72}8=\color{red}{69}$$

Answer (score 4):

Let     me     post     a     pointer.      The     following     [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2584928/)  from  eleven
months  ago  features  *orbital chromatic  polynomials*,  which  count
proper   colorings  of   a   graph  under   the   symmetries  of   its
automorphisms. There is extensive documentation at that link. The code
that was posted there is easy to apply here: the underlying graph with
edges for adjacency this the  three-by-three grid graph.  We encode it
as follows:

```
SQUARE3BY3 :=
proc()
option remember;

    return
    [9,
     {{1, 2}, {2, 3},
      {4, 5}, {5, 6},
      {7, 8}, {8, 9},
      {1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6},
      {4, 7}, {5, 8}, {6, 9}},

     [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], # identity
      [3,6,9,2,5,8,1,4,7], # 90 degrees
      [7,4,1,8,5,2,9,6,3], # -90 degrees
      [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1], # 180 degrees

      [7,8,9,4,5,6,1,2,3], # horizontal flip
      [3,2,1,6,5,4,9,8,7], # vertical flip

      [1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6,9],    # falling diagonal
      [9,6,3,8,5,2,7,4,1]]];  # rising diagonal

end;
```

The Maple  command **OCP(SQUARE3BY3());** then immediately  yields the
OCP:

$$P(k) = 1/8\,{k}^{9}+8\,k-{\frac {133\,{k}^{2}}{4}}-3/2\,{k}^{8}
+{\frac {33\,{k}^{7}}{4}}-{\frac {53\,{k}^{6}}{2}}
+{\frac {217\,{k}^{5}}{4}}-{\frac {291\,{k}^{4}}{4}}
+{\frac {507\,{k}^{3}}{8}}.$$

This yields for up to twelve colors the sequence

$$0, 2, 69, 1572, 19865, 153480, 830802, 3476144, 12003462,
\\35757630, 94780235, 228579252, \ldots$$

which confirms the value for three colors that was first to appear.

**Remark, as  per comments.** The value $P(k)$ of  this OCP counts
the number  of colorings  using at  most $k$  colors.  We  can compute
$P'(k)$ which gives  the proper colorings using exactly  $k$ colors by
inclusion-exclusion. Here  the nodes of  the poset are subsets  $Q$ of
$[k]$ representing proper colorings using some subset of the colors in
$Q$, which is counted by $P(|Q|).$ A coloring using exactly the colors
from  some  set $R$  is  represented  by  all nodes  corresponding  to
supersets  $Q$ of  $R.$  With the  weight  being $(-1)^{k-|Q|}$  those
colorings using exactly  $k$ colors only occur at  $Q=[k]$ with weight
$(-1)^{k-|Q|} = (-1)^{0} = 1.$ A coloring using exactly $R\subset [k]$
colors is  represented by all $Q$  such that $R \subseteq  Q \subseteq
[k]$, with total weight

$$\sum_{R'\subseteq [k] \setminus R} (-1)^{k-|R\cup R'|}
= (-1)^{k-|R|}
\sum_{r=0}^{|[k]\setminus R|} {|[k]\setminus R| \choose r} (-1)^{-r}
= 0.$$

Hence only  the colorings  with exactly $k$  colors contribute  and we
find

$$P'(k) = \sum_{Q\subseteq [k]} (-1)^{k-|Q|} P(|Q|) =
\sum_{q=0}^k {k\choose q} (-1)^{k-q} P(q).$$

This gives the finite sequence

$$0, 2, 63, 1308, 12675, 56520, 120960, 120960, 45360, 0, \ldots$$

because it  is clearly impossible  to color  the grid using  more than
nine distinct colors.  Observe also  the entry for three colors, which
is $P(3) - {3\choose 2} P(2) = 69 - 3\times 2$ i.e. we have subtracted
the colorings using two colors (there  are no coloring using one color
and hence $P(2)$ counts colorings  with exactly two colors). Also note
that with nine colors all orbits have the same size, namely eight, and
indeed we  obtain $9!/8 =  45360.$ As to  what happens when  there are
more than nine colors we can recover $P(k)$ as follows:

$$\sum_{q=0}^9 {k\choose q} P'(q).$$

**Addendum.**  The reader  might be  interested  to know  that we  can
compute  the  OCP  for  larger  grids, using  the  following  code  in
conjunction with the quoted link:

```
SQUARE :=
proc(n)
    option remember;
    local src, rot, automs, edges, v2n;

    src := [seq(seq([p, q], q=0..n-1), p=0..n-1)];

    edges :=
    {seq(seq({[p, q], [p+1, q]},
             p=0..n-2), q=0..n-1),
     seq(seq({[p, q], [p, q+1]},
             p=0..n-1), q=0..n-2)};

    rot := v -> [v[2], n-1-v[1]];

    automs :=
    [src, # identity
     map(rot, src),                    #  90 degrees
     map(v -> rot(rot(v)), src),       # 180 degrees
     map(v -> rot(rot(rot(v))), src),  # 270 degrees

     map(v -> [n-1-v[1], v[2]], src),  # horizontal flip
     map(v -> [v[1], n-1-v[2]], src),  # vertical flip

     map(v -> rot([n-1-v[1], v[2]]),
         src),  # rising diagonal
     map(v -> rot(rot(rot([n-1-v[1], v[2]]))),
         src)]; # falling diagonal

     v2n :=
     [seq(seq([p, q] = 1 + p*n + q, q=0..n-1), p=0..n-1)];

    [n*n, subs(v2n, edges), subs(v2n, automs)];
end;
```

We obtain for a four-by-four the OCP

$$1/8\,{k}^{16}-3\,{k}^{15}+{\frac {69\,{k}^{14}}{2}}
-{\frac {2015\,{k}^{13}}{8}}+{\frac {10437\,{k}^{12}}{8}}
\\-{\frac {20307\,{k}^{11}}{4}}+15333\,{k}^{10}-{\frac {292907\,{k}^{9}}{8}}
-{\frac {848501\,{k}^{7}}{8}}+{\frac {1023195\,{k}^{6}}{8}}
\\-{\frac {240539\,{k}^{5}}{2}}+{\frac {557915\,{k}^{8}}{8}}
-{\frac {8807\,k}{4}}+{\frac {112831\,{k}^{2}}{8}}
+{\frac {683997\,{k}^{4}}{8}}-{\frac {347485\,{k}^{3}}{8}}$$

with the sequence

$$0, 1, 1155, 759759, 103786510, 4767856260, 107118740001, \ldots$$

We get for a five-by-five the OCP

$$1/8\,{k}^{25}+{\frac {69997383\,{k}^{17}}{8}}-5\,{k}^{24}
+{\frac {195\,{k}^{23}}{2}}-1233\,{k}^{22}+{\frac {45399\,{k}^{21}}{4}}
\\-80919\,{k}^{20}+{\frac {928545\,{k}^{19}}{2}}
-{\frac {17590911\,{k}^{18}}{8}}-{\frac {118477969\,{k}^{16}}{4}}
+{\frac {172111059\,{k}^{15}}{2}}
\\-{\frac {1726958987\,{k}^{14}}{8}}
+{\frac {3754019329\,{k}^{13}}{8}}-{\frac {1770719251\,{k}^{12}}{2}}
\\+{\frac {5797425049\,{k}^{11}}{4}}-2053661272\,{k}^{10}
+{\frac {20055169857\,{k}^{9}}{8}}+{\frac {9236896437\,{k}^{7}}{4}}
\\-{\frac {6780818949\,{k}^{6}}{4}}+{\frac {8083053959\,{k}^{5}}{8}}
-{\frac {20932696169\,{k}^{8}}{8}}+4017958\,k
\\-{\frac {145271789\,{k}^{2}}{4}}-{\frac {3768579695\,{k}^{4}}{8}}
+{\frac {1292510453\,{k}^{3}}{8}}$$

with the sequence

$$0, 2, 76332, 2557101612, 6352711134515, 2747239197568620,
\\378972203462839707, \ldots$$

Comment: What happens when you color 9 cells with >9 colors?

Comment: @amI ...nothing happens, except that more colourings appear.

Comment: but aren't the unique colorings reduced?

Comment: I have added some commentary.